# SQL List data from table dependant on data from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a CMS for a client who wishes for a sorting of his data by upcoming activities.

There is a table named `customers` which contains all of the customers, identified by the `cust_id` column.

There is also a table named `activities`, in which there is a `cust_id` column to pair it with a customer, and a `date_last_done` field to specify when the task was completed. The customer can have many activities to their record.

I want to fetch all customers where the most recent (`date_last_done` desc) activity was completed more than 11 months ago.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    customers
INNER JOIN
    activities
ON
    activities.cust_id = customers.cust_id
WHERE
    (SELECT
        date_last_done
    FROM
        activities
    WHERE
        cust_id = ???
    ORDER BY
        date_last_done
    DESC)
    < date() - 11months
```

How would I edit my query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the `customers` table with a subquery that returns the customers with activity that fits the criteria.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers AS c
JOIN (SELECT cust_id
      FROM activities
      GROUP BY cust_id
      HAVING MAX(date_last_done) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)) AS a
ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
```

Comment: Fantastic answer - I've not used this logic before. There's an issue with a missing bracket just before the `AS a ON c.cust_id`. Also, there is an error thrown declaring that `FUNCTION db.MAX()` does not exist?

Comment: Fixed the missing bracket, not sure about the error, though. Make sure you don't have a space after `MAX`.

Comment: Spot on. PHPMyAdmin formatted the SQL and added a new line there. Many thanks!